# Can't install/update packages using pip or conda

Tags: import, anaconda, installation, conda

I'm unable to install or update any package using the terminal using either  pip or conda install/update. Also my anaconda navigator will not open.

I believe I may have messed with my conda env somehow without realizing. I've tried restarting my computer and updating my MacOS.

### conda info

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/annaberman/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/annaberman/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/annaberman/.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.1
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : /Users/annaberman/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/annaberman/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/annaberman/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/annaberman/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/annaberman/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.1 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Darwin/17.7.0 OSX/10.13.6
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

## Error Messages:

### Conda error

```
$ conda install geopandas

Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",))',),)
```

### Pip Error

```
$ pip install geopandas

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting geopandas
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/geopandas/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/geopandas/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/geopandas/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/geopandas/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/geopandas/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/geopandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/geopandas/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geopandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for geopandas
```

### Anaconda Open Error

```
$ anaconda-navigtor

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/annaberman/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/annaberman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 103, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "/Users/annaberman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/start.py", line 34, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
  File "/Users/annaberman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/widgets/main_window.py", line 37, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.analytics import GATracker
  File "/Users/annaberman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/analytics.py", line 44, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.external.UniversalAnalytics import Tracker
  File "/Users/annaberman/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/external/UniversalAnalytics/Tracker.py", line 28, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import (HTTPSHandler, Request, build_opener,
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'
```

Comment: Have there been any recent changes to your **base** env? (Check `/Users/annaberman/anaconda3/conda-meta/history`). I'd be looking for something like changes to `six`, `requests`, `openssl`, `libssl`, `conda`.

Comment: Also, have you been using `pip` in your **base** env? That's definitely something to avoid as it typically makes any env you run it in unstable. See "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)" for details.